# Import Pyodbc error while running a python script on pycharm on mac

Tags: pyodbc, importerror

I'm getting pyodbc import error while i'm trying to run a python script on pycharm

I have already tried `pip install pyodbc` , and also `brew install unixodbc`
I'm still getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s0s0qw4/astro-airflow-localdev/dags/dremio.ak.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/s0s0qw4/astro-airflow-localdev/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/s0s0qw4/astro-airflow-localdev/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file)
```

I have tried to uninstall pyodbc and reinstall. I'm getting the below error:

```
import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/s0s0qw4/astro-airflow-localdev/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libodbc.2.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/s0s0qw4/astro-airflow-localdev/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the docs for pyodbc have to say about installing for mac:

> Installing on MacOSX
> Binary wheels for MacOSX are published for most Python versions, so no further action is needed before installing pyodbc.
> Note: You may need to install unixODBC as well, e.g. using brew install unixodbc.
> Macs with M1 ARM chips may need additional compiler and linker options set in order to install pyodbc:
>
> ```bash
> brew install unixodbc  
> export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/[your version]/lib"  
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/[your version]/include"  
> pip install pyodbc
> ```

> where `[your version]` would be, for example, 2.3.11. Check the value with `odbcinst -j` (after installing unixODBC).
> Alternatively, if you're still getting errors, try installing directly from the source distribution instead by using `pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc`.